# Polling S3 Bucket for file using Spring integration

Tags: java, spring, amazon-s3, spring-integration, polling

I am working on a project where I am required to poll S3 bucket for files and upload in a different S3 bucket. As a first step to implementing it, I am trying to poll S3 bucket for new files created and create them in my local directory using Spring Integration. To achieve that I have created a simple spring-boot application with maven with the below object polling configuration while handles the fileReading IntegrationFlow

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableAsync
public class ObjectPollerConfiguration {
    @Value("${amazonProperties.bucketName}")
    private String bucketName;
    public static final String OUTPUT_DIR2 = "target2";
    @Autowired
    private AmazonClient amazonClient;
    @Bean
    public S3InboundFileSynchronizer s3InboundFileSynchronizer() {
        S3InboundFileSynchronizer synchronizer = new S3InboundFileSynchronizer(amazonClient.getS3Client());
        synchronizer.setDeleteRemoteFiles(true);
        synchronizer.setPreserveTimestamp(true);
        synchronizer.setRemoteDirectory(bucketName);            
        return synchronizer;
    }
    @Bean
    @InboundChannelAdapter(value = "s3FilesChannel", poller = @Poller(fixedDelay = "30"))
    public S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource() {
        S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource messageSource =
                new S3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(s3InboundFileSynchronizer());
        messageSource.setAutoCreateLocalDirectory(true);
        messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File("."));
        messageSource.setLocalFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<File>());
        return messageSource;
    }
    @Bean
    public PollableChannel s3FilesChannel() {
        return new QueueChannel();
    }
    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow fileReadingFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(s3InboundFileSynchronizingMessageSource(),
                        e -> e.poller(p -> p.fixedDelay(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .handle(fileProcessor())
                .get();
    }
    @Bean
    public MessageHandler fileProcessor() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler handler = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(OUTPUT_DIR2));
        handler.setExpectReply(false); // end of pipeline, reply not needed
        return handler;
    }
}*
```

But when I start my application as a java application and upload files to S3, I don't see the target2 directory with file nor getting any logs corresponding to polling execution. Can someone help me to get it working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem that you don't use your `OUTPUT_DIR2` property for local dir to push into.

Your code for local dir is like this:

```
messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File("."));
```

This is fully not what you are looking for.
Try to change it into the

```
messageSource.setLocalDirectory(new File(OUTPUT_DIR2));
```

Comment: Thanks Artem. Lemme try. Meanwhile I have created publish event for S3 object upload and consuming that

Comment: I am working on a usecase where I am supposed to poll S3 -> read the stream for the image content -> do some processing and upload it to another bucket rather than writing the file in my server. Can you help me with implementing this using S3StreamingMessageSource ?

Comment: Lemme create a question for that. Please answer that

Comment: Please, don't push Open Source community. We help on will. If we decide do not answer, you won't hear from us. There is really some work to do on our side as well... Respect time and resources of other people.

Comment: I am really sorry for asking for help that way. I understand and I respect the time and resources of other people. Will ensure that I don't put it that way hereafter